# Calculating percentage of particular value against sum of all values when the other values are all 0s

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame of questionnaire data which has undergone processing. Each column measures a particular construct in binary terms (1 represent yes; 0 represent no; NA are blanks).

A sample of the data frame is as follow:

```
df <- data.frame(qol1 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0, 0, 1, NA, 0), 
             qol2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
             qol3 = c(1, 0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))

df
   qol1 qol2 qol3
1     1    0    1
2     0    0    0
3     0    0   NA
4     1    0   NA
5    NA   NA   NA
6     0    1    0
7     0    0    0
8     1    0    0
9    NA    0    1
10    0    0    1
```

I would like to calculate the percentage of 1s over the total number of 1s and 0s (ignoring the NAs) for each column.

I have attempted to use the following code, but it did not result in the correct answer because anything that adds 0 will result in the same number:

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(. == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(., na.rm = TRUE)*100))
```

I have thought of using `nrow`, `count`, etc, but they do not have an argument for na.rm.

The desired outcome I would like is:

```
qol1  qol2  qol3
37.5  11.11 42.85
```

Thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: Try `df %>% summarise_all(~sum(.==1, na.rm = T)/sum(.<=1, na.rm = T))`. You are using `sum(., na.rm = TRUE)` in the denominator, which just adds the `1`s, when you actually need to count `1`s and `0`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `is.na` and `sum` over them to calculate non-NA values

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(. == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/sum(!is.na(.))*100))

#  qol1     qol2     qol3
#1 37.5 11.11111 42.85714
```

---

A base R option with same logic

```
colSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/colSums(!is.na(df)) * 100

# qol1     qol2     qol3 
#37.50000 11.11111 42.85714
```

---

Or even simpler, since the input contains only 1,0 and `NA`s

```
colMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE) * 100

# qol1     qol2     qol3 
#37.50000 11.11111 42.85714
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `mean()` in base R:

```
sapply(df, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) * 100)

    qol1     qol2     qol3 
37.50000 11.11111 42.85714

# or more concisely:
sapply(df, mean, na.rm = TRUE) * 100
```

Same logic in `dplyr`

```
summarise_all(df, mean, na.rm = TRUE) * 100
  qol1     qol2     qol3
1 37.5 11.11111 42.85714
```